# Show product mage from on image click event in another form VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to display the image of a product when it is clicked on in another form because on the first form the image size is small so I want it to show on a bigger form when its clicked on

code that shows the product image when the product is clicked on

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Dim strFile As String

Me.cmb_Product.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
iPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\" & Me.cmb_Product.Value & ".JPG"
iPathNA = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\NA.jpg"

strFile = iPath

If Len(Dir(strFile)) <> 0 Then
    ItemImage.Picture = LoadPicture(strFile)
Else
    ItemImage.Picture = LoadPicture(iPathNA)
End If

End Sub
```

code on image click event

```
Private Sub ItemImage_Click()
productImage.Show False
End Sub
```

code in 2nd form

```
Private Sub productImage_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
productImage.Picture = LoadPicture(frm_Inventory_Management.iPathNA)
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `ItemImage`, since it does not look to be an `Image` control? An `Image` control does not expose a Click` event... Then, don't you want the image to be displayed immediately after the form is shown?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood what you try doing, please try the next way:

1. Declare the used variable as `Public`, on top of the user form code module (in the declarations area):

```
    Public strFile As String 'the exposed variable to be used
```

2. Use your adapted list box click event as (only without declaration of the above variable):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
   Me.cmb_Product.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
   iPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\" & Me.cmb_Product.Value & ".JPG"
   iPathNA = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\NA.jpg"

   strFile = iPath

   If Len(Dir(strFile)) <> 0 Then
       ItemImage.Picture = LoadPicture(strFile)
   Else
       ItemImage.Picture = LoadPicture(iPathNA)
   End If
End Sub
```

3. If `ItemImage` is an `Image` control, it does not expose a `Click` event, so try using its `MouseUp` event:

```
  Private Sub ItemImage_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
       productImage.Show False
End Sub
```

If `ItemImage` is a control exposing the `click` event, use it as it is.

Note: The form `frm_Inventory_Management` must have the `ShowModal` property = `False`.

4. You should use the `Initialize` event of the shown userform:

```
  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     Me.Picture = LoadPicture(frm_Inventory_Management.strFile)
  End Sub
```

In this way it will load the existing picture on the specific control

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: I later got the code right thank you very much But I did so on the form initialize event

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me later on

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim strFile As String


iPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\" & frm_Inventory_Management.cmb_Product.Value & ".JPG"
iPathNA = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Item Images\NA.jpg"

strFile = iPath

If Len(Dir(strFile)) <> 0 Then
    productImage.Picture = LoadPicture(strFile)
Else
    productImage.Picture = LoadPicture(iPathNA)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @FaneDuru this is the code that worked